# C %p printing 16 instead of 8 bytes

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I need to print the address of a pointer.
This is my code：

```
float arr[5] = {1.2 , 2.3 , 5 , 7.1 , 9.6};
float *ptrarr;
ptrarr = &arr[0];

printf("Address of ptrarr+2=%p,%p \n\n",ptrarr+2,&arr[2]);
```

I knew that pointer addresses have 8 bytes, but my output is always 16 bytes.
This is the output

```
Address od ptarr+2=000000000061FDE8,000000000061FDE8
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Please don't post images of text, code, error messages etc. Copy the text and paste it as text into the question.

Comment: this is hexadecimal. Each byte is coded as 2 bytes

Comment: The output shows two numbers of 8 bytes each, represented in base 16 (hexadecimal). Read about [base 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). A byte contains 8 bits; there are 16 hexadecimal digits, each of them is represented on 4 bits. Therefore, in base 16, one byte is represented by exactly 2 hexadecimal digits.

Comment: Pointer size depends on CPU architecture, on 32bit CPU's it will by 4 bytes

Comment: @Cy-4AH: Pointer size is determined by the C implementation, not by the CPU architecture. The CPU and the operating system are commonly major influences in a typical C implementation, but they are not conclusive. I worked with a C implementation that used 32-bit pointers in a system with a 64-bit address space. It was intended to reduce the memory footprint of processes using a lot of memory structures connected together by many pointers. Another example is a special-purpose C implementation might be designed to support an old environment in modern hardware, so that old software can be used.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it was just application build for 32bit architecture running on 64bit processor. When you compile your sources, you identify for which architecture it's compiled, at that moment pointer size is determined. Any way on 32bit CPU program with 64bit pointers will not run.

Comment: @Cy-4AH: As I wrote, the C implementation used 32-bit pointers in a system with 64-bit addresses. `sizeof(char *)` yielded four, but the hardware instructions used 64 bits for addresses. A pointer in C and a hardware address in instructions may be different things.

Comment: Sorry @EricPostpischil, I think you misunderstand me. I was talking about CPU architecture for which you compile application, not about CPU architecture on which you are running it. Of course 4byte pointers in 32bit application will not became 8byte pointers if you run it on 64bit CPU.

Comment: @Cy-4AH: The C implementation I am describing targeted applications running in 64-bit mode on a 64-bit processor. The compiler was not told to build for a 32-bit target. It was a C implementation which used 32-bit pointers in a 64-bit address space. This means not all of the address space was available through C pointers. (Additional address space may have been used by non-C code linked into the executable, or by code that was C but came from a different C implementation.) But the point is the hardware used 64-bit address, but that did not mean the C pointers were 64 bits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**On a platform where the number of bits per byte is 8:**

1 hexadecimal character represents 4 bits, i.e., "half a byte".

Hence 16 hexadecimal characters represent 8 bytes (not 16 bytes).

---

Note that generally, the number of bits per byte is define by `CHAR_BIT`.

So on the theoretical aspect, a byte can consist of something other than 8 bits.